# How to filter files that sbt watches for changes?

Tags: scala, sbt

I use emacs as my editor, and it has a nasty habit of creating locks for files near those files. It seems that sbt treats that locks as source files as well, and this results in a lot of unnecessary rebuilds.

Is there a way to tell sbt that it shouldn't watch for changes in the files, whose names start with `.#`?

I tried something along the lines of:

```
watchSources in Compile <<= (watchSources in Compile) map { files =>
  println(files)
  files.filter(f => !f.getName.startsWith(".#"))
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*watchSources* is not used as a scoped setting. Rewrite your example without *in Compile* and it will work.

Comment: It seems to work, partially - at least the right file names are printed. But it seems that sbt triggers reload also when a new ".#" file is created, and it is not passed through "watchSources". Is there some way to tell it not to trigger rebuild on newly created files with that prefix?

Answer (score 4):

SBT ignores Emacs Auto Save Mode files if I add the following line to `project/Build.scala` inside the `ApplicationBuild`:

```
excludeFilter in unmanagedSources := ".#*"
```

in the newer style sbt syntax, that's:

```
unmanagedSources / excludeFilter := ".#*"
```

Comment: This solution seems to be working when used in a build.sbt file as well.